# Run a bot in different sessions on same server

Tags: automationanywhere

I have an Automation Server where both the Control Room and the clients are installed. The Automation Server is accessed from another Main Server and so the Control Room. I have created some clients in the Control Room from the Main Server. I have logged in to 3 different sessions of the Automation Server and also logged in to the Clients which were created in the Control Room on the Main Server.Now, when i am trying to run a bot from the Main Server, the bot is running on the Automation Server but only in the first client logged in even if i have not selected it. Can anyone help or suggest anything about this issue?

I am expecting to run a bot from the Control Room of the Main Server into the Automation Server into the selected clients.

Comment: Can anyone help with the above architect?

Comment: what version of AA are you on?